# Solving the system $a + b = x$, $2a = b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a Web Developer and I am trying to solve some margin issues.

The issue I had initially was that I wanted $x$ to be $10$ (the margin between each column needed to be $10\mathrm{px}$), but with the above equation that would lead to
$$\begin{align*}
a = 3.33\\
b = 6.66\\
x = 9.99
\end{align*}$$

But for example if $x$ was $8$ or $12$, is there a calculation to quickly figure this out?

Comment: $a = x/3, b = 2x/3$, that's the most simple way you may get $a$ and $b$ from $x$.

Comment: Wicked, thank you. So annoyed I didn't get that myself as it looks so simple!

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the tag now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the system
$$\begin{cases}
a + b = x\\
2a = b
\end{cases}$$

substituting $b$ from the second equation in the first one you get
$$\begin{cases}3a = x\\
2a = b
\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}
a = \frac x3\\[0.5em]
b = \frac{2x}3
\end{cases}$$